# customizing slider to look like the one in a native application (Reminders App in IOS5)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5

I am badly stuck in this. I want to have a control in iOS 4 (either slider or page control) to look exactly like the one in Reminders App of iOS 5 (at the bottom of the Date Tab). If anybody knows how to customize this in iOS 4 to look like reminders app, then please help me.